Configure systemd-resolved to try multicast dns for `.local` names and fall back to unicast dns if multicast can't resolve
I have machines that run in all kinds of environments which aren't under my control and I need to configure them to work in all of those.
My current issue is, that some environments have a .local domain which is resolved using unicast dns (which is against the standard) while others might use the mdns.
With /etc/nsswitch.conf you were able to set hosts:    files mdns_minimal dns which would try mdns first and then fall back to regular unicast dns if it couldn't resolve the name using mdns.
With systemd-resolved, it seems that you can enable or disable multicast dns using the MulticastDNS setting, but I wonder if there is a way to achieve the same "fallback system".
It seems that currently, systemd-resolved tries multicast dns for .local names and fail if it can't resolve them by default.

So I think I came up with a solution just after posting this.
If I set /etc/nsswitch.conf up so a client will try to resolve using mdns before dns and then set MulticastDNS=false I would probably get the desired behavior.
I will try to remember to update this answer when I confirmed that it works.
